# How do I setup a software raid 1 on 2 newly installed HD's in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.10, raid, software-raid, raid-1

I setup a HTPC about a month ago, and just expanded my storage by adding two 750GB drives in addition to my OS drive.  I am using Ubuntu 9.10 as my OS and need help setting up a raid 1 on the two 750GB drives.

gparted shows the two drives as /dev/sdb and /dev/sdc

Answer (score 1):

OK I found out how.  http://www.devil-linux.org/documentation/1.0.x/ch01s05.html